# Error connecting to Consul agent

Tags: consul

I have a consul server running on ubuntu box via vagrant and virtual box
It appears to be running correctly:

[image: running server]

I then ssh onto the box and run:

```
consul members
```

but I get this output:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
I cant figure this out as I am following consul tutorial, and it seems to have no issue with this

Adding config.json file

```
{
    "bootstrap": true,
    "server": true,
    "datacenter": "dc1",
    "data_dir": "/var/consul",
    "encrypt": "Dt3P9SpKGAR/DIUN1cDirg==",
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "enable_syslog": true,
    "bind_addr": "172.20.20.10",
    "client_addr": "172.20.20.10"
}
```

Comment: You should post a link to the consul tutorial you are following.

Comment: Tutorial I am using to learn commands is http://www.consul.io/intro/getting-started/install.html, however this does not configure everything I have in config.json above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consul [defaults to the client address of 127.0.0.1](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_client), but you have configured your server to listen on 172.20.20.10 for clients.

You'll need to put the option `-rpc-addr` to your command line invocation as well to make it work:

```
consul members -rpc-addr=172.20.20.10:8400
```

I'm also the author of an example Consul setup with Vagrant and Saltstack, maybe [you want to have a look at the Github repository](https://github.com/ahus1/saltconsul-examples).

Comment: Very new to consul and still getting started. I did the following root@consulserver1:~# exec consul agent -config-file=/etc/consul.d/config.json -client=172.20.20.10 which is what I believe you are saying but still have the same issue

Comment: Please add the `-client` parameter to the `consul members` command. It should look like this `consul members -client=172.20.20.10`

Comment: Sorry, I did give the wrong command line option. `-client` is the option for the agent command, while `-rpc-addr` is the right option for the members command. Answer updated.

Comment: thanks ahus, working for me now. Will read your setup article the weekend

Answer (score 3):

Run the following command to start consul in bootstrap mode.

```
consul agent -config-dir ~/consul-config/server -ui-dir ~/consul-ui -bootstrap true -client=0.0.0.0
```

To setup consul on a single instance follow [this blog post](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/05/setup-consul-single-server.html) or [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVKveB-2bGQ)